# How to alter and manipulate the behavior and action of button through extension?

Tags: api, extension, hooks, contribution-page, gsoc

I want to alter and manipulate the behavior and action of continue button on new contribution page through extension, I want to do some additional tasks with that button through my extension like sending email etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use hook_civicrm_postProcess or hook_civicrm_post

which ever you need based on your requirement below is the link for more reference http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference